# Pushing to a remote repository from local clone automatically deletes commits

Tags: git

I have a server on GoDaddy and I have sshed to it to create a remote repository. On my local machine, I have cloned this repository and I have tried to commit a new file and push it to the remote repo. After typing git status on my remote repo I get this:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       deleted:    tester.c
#
```

How can I commit the file without deleting it? Why is it trying to delete my committed file?

Comment: You should only be seeing this if you or something else actually deleted `tester.c`.  Does this file still exist on your local filesystem?

Comment: The file is still intact on my local machine.

Comment: And is this file also where you made your changes?

Comment: Yes. I have just again tried to create another file "anothertest.c" on my local machine and performed the following commands. 

git add anothertest.c
git commit -m 'test'
git push origin master

Comment: Just do `git add tester.c` and then commit.  For some reason, you have a delete operation on this file staged.  I really hope you didn't just do a commit!

Comment: I have tried that. I have done those commands to no avail ;(

Comment: `git reset HEAD tester.c`

Comment: I don't understand why this is happening. Why are these commits automatically set to be deleted unless I unstage them? If I do `git reset HEAD tester.c` then I get
`# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       deleted:    tester.c
#`
and if I were to use the git checkout command, it appears to place the file in my remote repo. Still confused though as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You noted that you have ssh access to your remote repository.

Once you ssh in to your remote repository, it's your *local* repository over there.  So what you have is two *local* repositories, each viewing the other as the foreigner.  You are allowing the foreigner to connect to your *local* machine (the server on GoDaddy) and *change* things on it.

**When you do this you must exercise great care.**  By default, Git will exercise this care for you, using the default setting for `receive.denyCurrentBranch`.  When you run `git push` from the foreign machine (your system at home), your local machine (the server) will *reject* the push, because you are using that on your local machine.

**You disabled the safety mechanisms** by changing the setting of `receive.denyCurrentBranch`.  Then you crashed your foreign machine into your local (server) machine, as if you were driving one car into another for doing a crash-test, and now you seem to have a file that has gone missing.  It's not actually missing, it's just that with all the safeties disabled, Git expects to you pick up all the nuts, bolts, tires, pistons, and so on and re-assemble them into a suitable car-like shape after each collision.  This is a pain in the butt, so don't do it.

#### In general, a server that receives pushes should have a "bare" repository

A bare repository is one with no work-tree.  Since it has no work-tree, there is never a collision.

In Git version 2.4 and later, you can set `receive.denyCurrentBranch` to `updateInstead`.  This will refuse a push *unless* the work-tree on the server has no ongoing work being done in it.  In that particular case, the receiving Git (on the server) will update the local work-tree to the newly pushed commit.  This is still not entirely safe—you might be editing a file and simply haven't written it *back* to the work-tree, yet—but is convenient for automatic deployment.  You still must not do development on the server, because of this "may be updated while you're not paying attention" aspect, and it's probably better to use a bare repository anyway.  But it is possible now.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thanks a lot.